# Interpreting Reduce output (in the recreational context of the 3n + 1 problem)

Tags: equation-solving

From time to time this site sees questions such as this
[274849](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274849/how-to-eliminate-a-constant-factor-from-an-expression-ideally-without-rules) or [165906](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165906/how-do-we-show-reduction-steps), involving multiplication by 3 and adding one, dividing by 2, that seem to be (somewhat coyly perhaps) about the [Collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) problem.

Enough! Let us make no bones about it! I like using unsolved, possibly even unsolvable, problems as recreation, sometimes unproductively like a dog chasing its own tail, and sometimes productively as a way of exploring new programming capabilities, in this case MMA (11.0.1.0, Windows 10). (NB I consider my likelihood of solving this problem to be infinitesimal; this is what makes the work recreational rather than frustrational.)

Like my previous question, today's is also about Reduce and understanding its conclusions - when applied to a closed form for Collatz cycles.

Now, one can apply Trace to Reduce, but as it says in the documentation under [Tracing Evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#15851) with incomparable understatement:

> Trace[expr] gives a list that includes all the intermediate
> expressions involved in the evaluation of expr. Except in rather
> simple cases, however, the number of intermediate expressions
> generated in this way is typically very large, and **the list returned**
> by Trace **is difficult to understand**. [emphasis added]

The result of Reduce I am working with runs to hundreds of terms and has a Depth of 12. *I would like to know more about strategies for dealing with such large output in order to find out what it means - and how MMA arrived at its conclusions.*

Here's the problem: using the Syracuse formulation of the Collatz problem (in which up and down steps alternate, and instead of dividing by 2 we divide by the largest power of two that divides), the iteration after $P \ge 2$ steps is given by

```
ClearAll[collatz, Q, q];  
Q[n_] := 2^Sum[Subscript[q, j], {j, 1, n}] ;
collatz[P_, n_] := (n (3^P ) + 3^(P - 1) + Sum[Q[i] 3^(P - i), {i, 2, (P - 1)}] + Q[P - 1])/Q[P]
```

where the $q_i$ are the individual divisors, and Q just accumulates them.

Evaluation of `collatz[P,n]` gives

$2^{-\sum _{j=1}^P q_j} \left(\sum _{i=2}^{P-1} 3^{P-i} 2^{\sum _{j=1}^i q_j}+2^{\sum _{j=1}^{P-1} q_j}+n 3^P+3^{P-1}\right)$

(with some tidying and symbol reordering we can get a nicer form, but I won't dwell on the details and won't use it

$\frac{3^P n+3^{P-1}+\frac{2^Q}{q_P}+\sum _{i=2}^{P-1} 3^{P-i} 2^{\sum _{j=1}^i q_j}}{2^Q}$

it's just easier to read)

Let's now try to extract some information from the equation that defines a cycle or loop of the Collatz function, i.e. `collatz[P,n] == n`

Now, we know of the {1, 4, 2} cycle, but there are also cycles in the negative integers, such as these (in Syracuse form, with their P, Q values)

- {-1,-2, 1}, P = 1, Q = 1
- {-5, -14, -7, -20, -5},P = 2, Q = 2
- {-17, -50, -25, -74, -37, -110, -55, -164, -41, -122, -61, -182, -91, -272, -17), P = 7, Q = 11

Now, apply Reduce to collatz[P,n] == n

```
cReductions = Reduce[collatz[P, n] == n, n, Integers, GeneratedParameters -> Subscript[Const, #] &) ];
```

This produces moderately large output of the form (A && B && (C1 || ... || C162)) (Side issue relating to Q274998: why did MMA not use Alternatives & Elements here, as $(a | b) \in  \mathbb{Z}$?)

Those first two terms, A, B are `cReductions[[1 ;; 2]]`

$3^{P-1}\in \mathbb{Z}\land 2^{-\sum _{j=1}^P q_j}\in \mathbb{Z}$

Hence the following questions, at last.

**Question 1**

The condition $2^{-\sum _{j=1}^P q_j}\in \mathbb{Z}$ is obviously wrong because we know of $Q = 2$ and $Q=11$ are possible for negative n (unless the sum of $q_i$ is negative, implying at least one must also be -ve, which doesn't make sense in context).

**How can I work out why MMA arrives at this erroneous conclusion? Is there some way to fix it?** I realise that my $q_i$ are not specified to be +ve anywhere, but it's not obvious to me how I could rectify that (or that the sum is positive).

**Question 2**

In [274998](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274998/reduce-over-integers-why-does-mma-not-give-impossible) I asked why MMA didn't eliminate things like this:

$2^{\sum _{j=1}^{P-1} q_j}=3 \text{Const}_1\land 2^{\sum _{j=1}^P q_j}=3 \text{Const}_2$

from the collection of OR'd terms (C) above. Now, I know that subscripted symbols are generally not recommended, but I hoped it wouldn't matter here. **Was I wrong?** How could I repose the equations or Reduce to facilitate this?

**Question 3**

Has anyone created any tools for overcoming the unreadability of Trace output?

Comment: For Question 1, a more minimal example is `Reduce[2^x*(k+2^y)==1,k,Integers]` where the output says that `2^x` and `2^y` are integers (in V12.3), yet this equation has the solution `{k,x,y}=={1,-1,0}` where `2^x` is not an integer. Before concluding that this is a bug, note that the documentation for `Reduce` says that the domain specification `Integers` applies to all variables, parameters, constants and *function values*. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable will tell us how to interpret this.

Comment: @user293787 Nice catch. I also found that documentation on Reduce to be unclear - let's hope someone can enlighten us. PS Actually, my docs say "If dom is Reals, or a subset such as Integers or Rationals, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be **real**. " Is there some other statement I missed?

Comment: @user293787 PS The preceding line is "Reduce[expr,vars,dom] restricts all variables and parameters to belong to the domain dom. " which seems contradictory to me.

Comment: That is the statement I meant. And you are right, it only says "to be real".